# azure function running locally - cron timer not using UTC

Tags: azure, azure-functions, ncron

I have an azure function timer with the following cron expression: `'0,30 * 0-8,21-23 * * *'`. I.e. every 30 seconds from 0-8 and 21-23 **UTC** (or at least I expect it to be UTC).

But now when I run my function locally using `func start`, I get the following:

```
[2021-11-24T06:45:15.531Z] The next 5 occurrences of the 'function_name' schedule (Cron: '0,30 * 0-8,21-23 * * *') will be:
[2021-11-24T06:45:15.533Z] 11/24/2021 21:00:30+11:00 (11/24/2021 10:00:30Z)
[2021-11-24T06:45:15.535Z] 11/24/2021 21:01:00+11:00 (11/24/2021 10:01:00Z)
...
```

Notice that the next X occurrences are using the local time zone (+11:00).  With the next trigger being at exactly `21:00:30+11:00`.

This is wrong (I think) and if you see the log timestamps (in UTC) you can see that we are NOW in the 0-8 window and should not need to wait for the 21-23 window.

Note: I am definitely not overriding the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting.

The command I use to run the function locally is: `func start`

[Edit] for clarity please see [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2109) I have opened on the Azure-Functions github page.

Comment: try running with the `func host start` command

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT no difference, infact `func start` is just the v2 version of `func host start`

Comment: Anyway, to make the cron expression looks clear, it's better to override the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting. And the messages you got may due to the runtime is in your local machine. Did you test the time trigger in azure?

Comment: The default time zone used with the CRON expressions is Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). To have your CRON expression based on another time zone, you have to create /override an app setting for your function app named `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`.

Still If not coming, the point to note here is `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` is not currently supported on the Linux Consumption plan.

Comment: Any update to the issue?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT not really.  I confirmed in the [bug report](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2109) that the ncron scheduler is ignoring the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE but I have not had any resolution or suggestion from MS.